# Trying to access into the GMX email inbox by using IMAP in PHP

Tags: php, connection, imap

I'm new at stack overflow and recently I've been facing a problem related to IMAP connections.I'm gonna be straightforward here.

I've an email account at "gmx.net" and I've been trying to have acces into my inbox by using IMAP connection. The credential

I've been using for such task and the relevant part of the code are:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmx.net:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$email    = 'myemail@gmx.de'; 
$password = 'mypass';
$conn = imap_open ($hostname, $email, $password) or die(imap_last_error());
$num_msgs = imap_num_msg($conn);
```

However, somehow I can't get connected to my gmx Inbox. The funny story is that I've used the same hostname pattern before ('{IMAP-SERVER-ADDRESS:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX') to connect to my gmail and other services for example and it worked as a charm.

I appreciate the help and I thank you in advance for your time.

Best regards,

M.J.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Thank you so much for your engagement legoscia, I really apreciate it, but I've found the problem. Somehow, my encryption process I was using to encrypt the password before saving it into the DB was interfering, and just after removing the encryption I was able to connect to IMAP server from GMX. The only question was why it did work for others IMAP servers but not for gmx. Anyway, thank you again :)